# Spark Job not returning consistent results

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a spark scala job that is selecting a score for a given interval. I've run this job against the same set of data 3 times, and each time I've gotten slightly different results for the score. My score is selected in a UDF that takes in a Seq and a number of how many scores to evaluate. Currently I am just evaluating one score so it *should* just return the highest score, but I'm not seeing a consistent high score returned. I'm not sure why this is happening, any help would be appreciated and I can add more info if needed.

```
RUN ONE:
    - Grab data from s3
    - Use pushdown predicates to get filtered data
    - Filter events with certain business rules, reapartiion, and mapPartition to clean up data
    - Filter data that is already good to go
    - Union the two dataframes
    - Join on small table
    - GroupBy & Aggregate to get a sum
    - GroupBy & Aggregate to get a List of sums
    - UDF with business logic to randomly select sum (currently just selecting highest sum)
    - Join on small table
    - Partition data and write to S3

RUN TWO:
    ** Same as Run One but I no longer repartition and I run the UDF after I join
    - Grab data from s3
    - Use pushdown predicates to get filtered data
    - Filter events with certain business rules and mapPartition to clean up data
    - Filter data that is already good to go
    - Union the two dataframes
    - Join on small table
    - GroupBy & Aggregate to get a sum
    - GroupBy & Aggregate to get a List of sums
    - Join on small table
    - UDF with business logic to randomly select sum (currently just selecting highest sum)
    - Partition data and write to S3

RUN THREE:
    ** Same as Run Two but passed in spark conf: spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=400
```

Comment: Compare the execution plans. If you notice a difference in how the udf is optimized, try mark the UDF as non-deterministic: `val myUdf = udf{ ... }.asNondeterministic`.

Answer (score 0):

spark internally divides data into partitions, and performs parallel computation using different core or machine which may result in inconsistency in data read order.

For example - if the file contains 1-1000 records and the file is divided into 6 partitions.
now if your cluster has only 4 cores available only 4 partitions can complete 2 will wait but out of those first 4 which will complete first is based on the data and computation
so spark doesn't provide a guarantee that 1st partition will complete first which can result in inconsistency if you are assuming that it will process data sequentially.

The above example is just for illustration.

this could be the reason why you are not getting consistent results. There are possible solutions which you can try -

1. either you can add explicit ordering in your data and then perform the computation.
2. if the file is not big then you can try to reduce
   the partition to 1 but this will result in a performance issue which
   is not recommended.
3. try to repartition data on a fixed number of
   partitions based on the key which results in the same partitions
   each time you run the job.
4. you are running this on the Hadoop cluster then you can turn off the speculation.

Thanks